# Pandas is either not finding a specific row of data or is detecting it as an empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big chunk of data that needs to be ordered read and then merged using pandas, my problem is that I noticed that pandas was returning "empty dataframe" on specific rows.

```
info = pd.read_excel("01. US Books.xlsx")
book3 = load_workbook("01. US Books.xlsx",data_only=True)
book3sheet=book3['US Projects']

for i in range(3,10,1):
 u = book3sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value
 print(str(u))
 desc = info[info["IDshorttext"].isin([str(u)])]
 print(desc)
```

This is the code I've used for testing, I'm using a for loop to make it go through a X number of rows before stopping since I only want certain rows of data, when I run the code it works but it returns certain rows as "empty dataframes"

For example my excel looks a little like this:

```
IDshorttext      X           Y           Z
 FR21AR3456    100000      234546    43434343

    6068871    486512       45465      454544


FR21AR34356 <-This one is read perfectly and returns the whole row as a dataframe
    6068871 <-These ones are returned as empty dataframes
```

In my excel file I got a lot of values on the first column that look like the previous examples but only the ones that look like this "6068871" aren't being read.

My question is: Is there something wrong with my code that makes those unable to be read or is the format of the excel file an issue?

Comment: Could you give us sample data?. But it doesn't only sketch it, I'm talking about something like `df = pd.DataFrame(....)`. Besides, would be nice you provide us with the data you're expecting as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your filter:

```
desc = info[info["IDshorttext"].isin([str(u)])]
```

Your Dataframe contains strings and integers. However, you always cast them as strings to compare them. Hence you are saying "give me the line that contains '6068871', a string." But there is only a line that contains 6068871, an integer.

try:

```
desc = info[info["IDshorttext"].isin([u])]
```

or

```
desc = info[info["IDshorttext"] == u]
```

There is not really a reason to use "isin()" if you only have one value, and not an array/list.

Comment: After asking the question, I continued testing and found out it was the filter as well. Thanks!